# module.exports with function

Tags: javascript, enums

I have several JavaScript files that I create enums. for example:

**source.enum.js**

```
const enumUtils = require('../enum.utils');

const EmailAddressesSourceType = enumUtils.createEnum([
    ['DIRECTORY', 'directory'],
    ['FILE', 'file'],
    ['ARRAY', 'array']
]);

module.exports = { EmailAddressesSourceType };
```

The **enum.utils.js** is just a file that do the simple function of creating an enum from array:

```
class EnumUtils {

    constructor() { }

    // This method takes a map of elements and converts them to freeze objects (an enum-like object).
    createEnum(mapItems) {
        if (!mapItems || mapItems.length <= 0) {
            throw new Error(`No array received: ${mapItems} (1000000)`);
        }
        const mapList = new Map([...mapItems]);
        const symbolMap = {};
        mapList.forEach((value, key) => { symbolMap[key] = value; });
        return Object.freeze(symbolMap);
    }
}

const enumUtils = new EnumUtils();
module.exports = enumUtils;
```

Now since I have 5-6 js files with enums, I want to avoid 'const enumUtils = require('../enum.utils');' in each of them, and do it all together in **index.js** file, something like this:

```
const { EmailAddressStatus, EmailAddressType, SendEmailStepName } = require('./files/emailAddress.enum');
const { Placeholder } = require('./files/placeholder.enum');
const { EmailAddressesSourceType } = require('./files/sources.enum');
const { Mode, Status, Method } = require('./files/system.enum');
const { StatusIcon, Color, ColorCode } = require('./files/text.enum');

const createEnum = (mapItems) => {
    if (!mapItems || mapItems.length <= 0) {
        throw new Error(`No array received: ${mapItems} (1000000)`);
    }
    const mapList = new Map([...mapItems]);
    const symbolMap = {};
    mapList.forEach((value, key) => { symbolMap[key] = value; });
    return Object.freeze(symbolMap);
};

module.exports = {
    createEnum(Color), createEnum(ColorCode), createEnum(EmailAddressStatus), createEnum(EmailAddressType), createEnum(EmailAddressesSourceType),
    createEnum(Method), createEnum(Mode), createEnum(Placeholder), createEnum(SendEmailStepName), createEnum(Status), createEnum(StatusIcon)
};
```

But, there are compilation error in:

```
module.exports = {
createEnum(Color), createEnum(ColorCode), createEnum(EmailAddressStatus), createEnum(EmailAddressType), createEnum(EmailAddressesSourceType),
createEnum(Method), createEnum(Mode), createEnum(Placeholder), createEnum(SendEmailStepName), createEnum(Status), createEnum(StatusIcon)
};
```

My question is, there is a workaround so enable me to reduce the 'const enumUtils = require('../enum.utils');' in each file of the enums js file?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

The error I'm getting is this:

[image]

The current status of the file (before I was trying to refactor) - It works OK:

**index.js**

```
const { EmailAddressStatus, EmailAddressType, SendEmailStepName } = require('./files/emailAddress.enum');
const { Placeholder } = require('./files/placeholder.enum');
const { EmailAddressesSourceType } = require('./files/sources.enum');
const { Mode, Status, Method } = require('./files/system.enum');
const { StatusIcon, Color, ColorCode } = require('./files/text.enum');

module.exports = {
    Color, ColorCode, EmailAddressStatus, EmailAddressType, EmailAddressesSourceType,
    Method, Mode, Placeholder, SendEmailStepName, Status, StatusIcon
};
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You can't expect it to know that the object keys should be named after the parameter. You have to write the object out in full: `module.exports = { Color: createEnum(Color), ColorCode: createEnum(ColorCode), ...`

Comment: Thanks @guy-incognito you saved me!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This guy, [guy-incognito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8898840/guy-incognito), solved for me the issue. Now it works like a charm. Thanks man!

```
const { EmailAddressStatus, EmailAddressType, SendEmailStepName } = require('./files/emailAddress.enum');
const { Placeholder } = require('./files/placeholder.enum');
const { EmailAddressesSourceType } = require('./files/sources.enum');
const { Mode, Status, Method } = require('./files/system.enum');
const { StatusIcon, Color, ColorCode } = require('./files/text.enum');

const createEnum = (mapItems) => {
    if (!mapItems || mapItems.length <= 0) {
        throw new Error(`No array received: ${mapItems} (1000000)`);
    }
    const mapList = new Map([...mapItems]);
    const symbolMap = {};
    mapList.forEach((value, key) => { symbolMap[key] = value; });
    return Object.freeze(symbolMap);
};

module.exports = {
    Color: createEnum(Color),
    ColorCode: createEnum(ColorCode),
    EmailAddressStatus: createEnum(EmailAddressStatus),
    EmailAddressType: createEnum(EmailAddressType),
    EmailAddressesSourceType: createEnum(EmailAddressesSourceType),
    Method: createEnum(Method),
    Mode: createEnum(Mode),
    Placeholder: createEnum(Placeholder),
    SendEmailStepName: createEnum(SendEmailStepName),
    Status: createEnum(Status),
    StatusIcon: createEnum(StatusIcon)
};
```